# Finding min/max in an array - Steps through a loop

Tags: arrays, loops, compare, max, min

I found a lot of solutions how to find the min or max of an int array. But I am not quiet sure how it works, so I am hoping somebody could explain me the steps through the loop.
I have a main class with 3 Cars and their cylinder capacity. So I found this example for a loop to find out which car has the highest cc.

```
int[] ccArr = {Car1.Engine, Car2.Engine, Car3.Engine};
int max = 100000;
        for (int i=0; i < ccArr.length; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j < ccArr.length; j++)
                if(ccArr[i] < ccArr [j])
                    max = ccArr[j];
```

So how does it work? I just cant get it in my head, what exactly these loops are doing. Your help is very much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Greetings

Comment: You don't need nested loops to find the max. One loop is enough.  Also, please tag a language.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite invalid, it should looke like this:

```
int[] ccArr = {Car1.Engine, Car2.Engine, Car3.Engine};
int max = ccArr[0];           //there exists at least 1 max value in array

//For every element in array (besides 1st, no need to compare it to max, as max = ccArr[0]) do:
    for (int i=1; i < ccArr.length; i++){
        if(ccArr[i] > max)  //If element's value is greater than max
            max=ccArr[i]    //Then set max's value to element's value
```